# How to Install Ruby version 3.1.2 on the self-hosted runner machine (ARC)

Tags: ruby, github-actions

I use [actions/actions-runner-controller](https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller)

I am trying to install ruby a specific version. I get error as mentioned below

```
Run ruby/setup-ruby@v1
with:
ruby-version: 3.1.2
bundler-cache: false

Error: The current runner (ubuntu-20.04-arm64) was detected as self-hosted because the platform does not match a GitHub-hosted runner image (or that image is deprecated and no longer supported).
In such a case, you should install Ruby in the $RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE yourself, for example using https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build
You can take inspiration from this workflow for more details: https://github.com/ruby/ruby-builder/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml
$ ruby-build 3.1.2 /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.2/arm64
Once that completes successfully, mark it as complete with:
$ touch /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.2/arm64.complete
It is your responsibility to ensure installing Ruby like that is not done in parallel.
```

I also tried to install it using RVM and RBENV, yet no luck. Any suggestions ?

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnupg2
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
\\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /etc/profile
source \~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm install ruby-3.1.2
```

I tried to install it using rvm and rbenv. I am still not able to install successfully.

This is not a Github hosted runner. This is third party self hosted runner hosted in EKS.

Refer: https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller

Comment: What errors do you get with `rvm` and `rbenv`?